# JQuery Mobile collapsible-set cloned divs`

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After cloning div's with .appendTo cloned ones just doesn't opens. so I have 2 divs which is opens ok, and all new generated is just doesn't react on mouse clicks.
I tried collapsed or open states they just doesn't react.

```
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 


for(i=1;i<10;i+=1){
$('#news_line').clone().attr('id',"news_line"+i).appendTo('#acc_news').trigger('create');

}

$('.title1').text("заголовки");
$('.ptext1').text("описание");

$('#acc_news').collapsibleset("refresh");

});
</script>

<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d" data-mini="true" id="acc_news">
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="news_line">

                          <h2>
                            <div class="title1">
                            &nbsp;
                            </div>
                          </h2>
                            <div class="ptext1">
                            &nbsp;
                            </div>
                </div>          
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="last_line">
                          <h2>
                            <div class="title1">
                            &nbsp;
                            </div>
                          </h2>

                            <div class="ptext1">
                            &nbsp;
                            </div>          
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of document.ready, use the jQM page events (pagecreate, pageinit, etc). Then as you are cloning an already enhanced dive, you don't need to call trigger('create') or refresh the collapsible set:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
  for(i=1;i<5;i+=1){
   $('#news_line').clone().attr('id',"news_line"+i).appendTo('#acc_news');
  }
  $('.title1').text("заголовки");
  $('.ptext1').text("описание"); 
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/uLBps)**

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you a lot! Sorry I can't vote yet:(

Comment: @Macron, you can just accept the answer so others will know the problem is solved.